# Validating data in PHP Tick box

Tags: php, forms, validation

if i have a form in html that requires a click of a button to accept T's and C's, how do I validate this in PHP?
I start with

```
<div>            
     <input type="checkbox" name="terms" id="tandc" value="yes" />
     <label for="tandc">Tick this box to confirm you have read our a href="#">terms and conditions</a></label>
</div>
```

then

```
            if(isset($_POST['terms'])) {
                $t_and_c = $_POST['terms'];
                    if ($t_and_c = empty($_POST['terms'])) {
                        echo'please click to confirm the T's and C's';
                    } else {
                        echo htmlentities($t_and_c);
                    }

                } else {
                echo'system error';
                }
```

When I don't click on t's and c's, it should say 'click here to confirm...'.
At the moment, it just says 'system error', so the 'terms' name key is not being recognised in the POST array. Any ideas?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['terms']) && empty($_POST['terms'])){ echo "error";} else{echo "success";}

Comment: @devpro unticked tick boxes are never set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate as like that:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['terms'])) 
{
    echo htmlentities($_POST['terms']);
} 
else {
    echo "please click to confirm the T's and C's";
}
?>
```

**Whats wrong with your code:**

- `$t_and_c = empty($_POST['terms']` you are not comparing this is assigning the value.
- `echo'please click to confirm the T's and C's';` this can not work because you are using single quote inside the single quotes.

Comment: What's the purpose of your (if(empty(..)) ?. An unchecked checkbox will not be defined, you do not need this code just to check.

Comment: @Sakuto: u r right my friend, here no need, in ist update of OP there was no input field, so i did it... thanks friend. .. answer updated .

Comment: The echo of it it's not really usefull either, since OP just need to check if it's checked, or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(isset($_POST['terms']))
    // user checked it
```

If it's not checked, the variable will not be set.

Answer (score 0):

comparison is with double = sign "==" corrected below

```
if ($t_and_c == empty($_POST['terms']))
```

Comment: otherwise it will not be a comparison. it will be an assignment and always evaluate true.

Comment: @RahulKate not if the expression returns false. He is checking the value of the assignment itself, rather than value of the expression. It's perfectly valid.